# Struggling with strong param conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tried to create a mailer using the following code:

routes code

```
resources :listings do
  member do
    put :lead
  end
end
```

mailer controller code

```
  def lead(listing)
    @listing = listing
    mail(to: @listing.leadrecepient, subject: "test")
  end
```

standard controller code

```
  def lead
    Enquiry.lead(@listing).deliver
  end
```

view

```
<%= form_for lead_listing_path(@listing), method: :put do |listing| %>
  <%= listing.text_field :name %>
  <%= listing.submit %>
<% end %>
```

In the context of a business directory, I want it so that there is a enquiry form on each listing page that when filled out and submitted, the information is sent to the relative listing email.

The problem however is that when I type into the form and click submit, I get the following error:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: listing
```

This seems to be because I have it in the "listing" controller which controls the showing and creation of the business listing itself. I therefore have strong params for a new listing which contains all the new listing variables:

```
  def listing_params
    params.require(:listing).permit(:fullname, :jobtitle, :email, :franchisename, :leadrecepint, :shortdescription, :longdescription, :website, :branchcount, :scale, :mininvestment, :investmentrange, :category, :hexbg, :logourl, :facebook, :twitter, :linkedin, :googleplus, :approved)
  end
```

I'm a beginner if I'm honest, any feedback or hints on how to fix it would be great. I just really want to get this form working.

Answer (score 2):

You call `form_for` incorrectly. It should be:

```
<%= form_for @listing, url: lead_listing_path(@listing), method: :put do |listing| %>
```

Comment: if missing first argument to the `form_for` this should raise error like `undefined method 'model_name' for Hash:Class`. I think problem OP in `listing_params` because `listing.text_field :name` not present in permit params.

Comment: @Зелёный you're probably wrong. Here's why: 1. If first argument to `form_for` is string (which is returned by `lead_listing_path` helper), it won't raise error. 2. The error is that whole `listing` is empty, not unpermitted `name` exists in `listing`. Which is exactly because of wrong argument passed into `form_for`.

Comment: oh i see =) just tested with `hash` instead `string`.

Comment: Hi Markek, I have implemented this however I am now getting undefined method `name'

Comment: These mailers are a nightmare! any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @JayMcNaught paste whole error message with backtrace in question.

Comment: @MarekLipka any idea?